# How to make element like css realtive but with spacing

Tags: css, position, padding, margin

I want element to behave as normal css relative positioning, but with one exception. I want to make this element padding/margin on the place where it is put after relative positioning.
Is it possible ? , plz help me guys

Ok I let you give an example:

```html
<div style="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div style="position:relative; background: pink; top: 40px; margin-bottom: 50px;">Second div relative position</div>
<div>Third div. Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div. Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div. Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div. Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.Third div.</div>
```

I want this pink element margin bottom affects div with Third div.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: what is wrong with my anwer? just devote??? pls more info if i misunderstood you

Comment: sorry bad click, I try to make my issue more clear

Answer (score 0):

It works totaly fine.

If you put an element in `position: relative` and `top: 40px`, the div is stil at `top: 0`, it just get's rendered 40px below that pixel.

So in your example you set `margin-bottom: 50px` and `top: 40px`.
Due to the 'offset' of 40px  to the bottom, your 'margines' are like:

`margin-top: 40px` -> because the 'top: 40px'

and

`margin-bottom: (pinkDivHight + 50px) - 40px`

```html
<div style="">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div style="position:relative; background: pink; top: 40px; margin-bottom: 50px;">Second div relative position</div>
<div>Third div.</div>
```

Comment: but if you want your div between the two divs, just use ``margin-top`` and ``margin-bottom`` and don't use ``top`` or sth. Should be waaay easyer and cleaner.